# Derivative of the matrix-valued function $f(x)=\exp(Ax+B)$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, matrix-calculus, matrix-exponential

Let
$$f(x)=e^{Ax+B}, \quad \text{for all }x\in\mathbb R$$
where $A,B$ are $n\times n$ matrice satisfying $AB+BA=0$.

If $B=0$, I know that the derivative is $Ae^{Ax}=e^{Ax}A$. But for the case $B\neq0$, I have no idea. Of course, it is possible to expand $f(x)$ in Taylor series to get a series solution, but I can't simplify it. Is there any other method to get the derivative of $f(x)$? Can the derivative be written in a simple form?

Comment: derivative with respect to what?

Comment: derivative with respect to x.

Comment: possible duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3867383/617446

Comment: isn't it just $Ae^{Ax + B}$?

Comment: No, because $A$ and $B$ don't commute in general.

Answer (score 2):

$
\def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\K#1{\frac{#1}{k!}}
\def\KK#1{\frac{#1}{(2k+1)!}}
\def\k{\K{\o}}
\def\Sz{\sum_{k=0}^\infty}
\def\Sk{\sum_{k=1}^\infty}
\def\Sj{\sum_{j=1}^k}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\m#1{\left[\begin{array}{r}#1\end{array}\right]}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
$Define the matrices
$$\eqalign{
X &= B+Ax, \qquad
F &= \exp(X) \;=\; I+\Sk\K{X^k} \\
}$$
and calculate their derivatives with respect to $x$ (using dot-notation)
$$\eqalign{
\dot X &= A, \qquad\qquad
\dot F &= \Sk\Sj\K{X^{j-1}A\:X^{k-j}} \\
}$$
That is the standard theoretical approach. However, if you have a reliable
algorithm for computing matrix exponentials, then a more *practical* approach
is to simply evaluate a block-triangular matrix
$$\eqalign{
\exp\LR{\m{X&A\\0&X}} &= \m{F&\dot F\\0&F} \\
}$$
and extract $\dot F$ from the $(1,2)$ block on the RHS.

---

NB:$\:$ The commutation relation between $A$ and $B$ is only useful
at $x=0$ where
$$\eqalign{
X &= B, \qquad
\dot F &= \LR{\Sz\KK{B^{2k}}}A \;=\; \fracLR{\sinh(B)}{B}A
}$$