# Differential of a matrix exponential

Tags: matrix-exponential

I need your help with the differential of a matrix exponential.

A function $f$ is a mapping from a matrix to a matrix, that is, $f: \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}\rightarrow  \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$.
Here $\mathbf{H} \in\mathbb{R}^{n \times n} $ is a matrix. And each element of $\mathbf{H}$ is parameterized by parameter $\theta$.

In this situation, I would like to know if it is correct
$$
\frac{d e^{f(\mathbf{H})}}{d \theta} = \frac{d f(\mathbf{H})}{d\theta}e^{f(\mathbf{H})}
$$

Comment: Not usually as  they do not commute. See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3872098/617446

Comment: Here you have the way to differentiate the exponential map : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative_of_the_exponential_map#Statement

Answer (score 1):

According to [this document](http://scipp.ucsc.edu/%7Ehaber/webpage/MatrixExpLog.pdf), it holds that
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\exp{\left( \mathbf{H}(t) \right)} = \exp{\left( \mathbf{H} \right)} \left\{ 
\mathbf{H}'-\frac{1}{2!}[\mathbf{H},\mathbf{H}']+\frac{1}{3!}[\mathbf{H},[\mathbf{H},\mathbf{H}']]-\frac{1}{4!}[\mathbf{H},[\mathbf{H},[\mathbf{H},\mathbf{H}']]]+\cdots 
\right\}
$$

where $[\mathbf{A},\mathbf{B}] = \mathbf{A}\mathbf{B}-\mathbf{B}\mathbf{A}$ and

$$
\mathbf{H}'=\frac{d}{dt}\mathbf{H}.
$$

So, the answer of the question is *no*.