# Express $\exp(A+B(t))$ as $\exp(A) + \cdots$

Tags: operator-theory, matrix-exponential

Consider two $n\times n$ matrices, $A$ and $B(t)$. Here $A$ is time independent, and $B(t)$ is time dependent such that $A$ and $B(t)$ don't necessarily commute.
I want to analyze $\exp(A+B(t))$. Ideally, I am looking to expand $\exp(A+B(t))$ in the form,

$$
\exp(A+B(t))
=
\exp(A) + \cdots,
$$

since I am interested in the difference $\exp(A+B(t))-\exp(A)$. I am also interested in some special forms of $B(t)$:

- $B_1(t) = \sum_{j=1}^p C_l t^l $, where $C_l$ are time independent matrices,
- $B_2(t) = \frac{d}{dt}, $
- $B(t) = B_1(t) + B_2(t)$.

Does anyone have any suggestions for formulas/approaches can be useful here?

Comment: Have you tried just working your way through a couple degrees of the series expansion of the $\exp$ function? What do you get? How does $\exp(A + B(t))$ differ from $\exp(A)\cdot \exp(B(t))$?

Comment: I doubt a simple series expansion of $\exp(A+B(t))$ using the definition of matrix exponential can me to write it as $\exp(A) + \cdots$. Perhaps I am wrong.

Comment: Of course you can. You get $\exp(A + B(t)) = \exp(A) + [-\exp(A) + \exp(A + B(t))]$. The question is whether there is any meaningful simplification to be done inside the square bracket. And you never know until you actually try. The series approach should be one of the first things you try once nothing obvious pops out at you. I would personally have tried that long before making a post here.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3872098/617446

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that $B(0) = 0$ (it is the case for $B_1$ and I don't understand what $B_2(t) = \frac{d}{dt}$ means), you can do a Taylor development around $0$ with,
$$
\exp(A + B(t)) = \exp(A) + d\exp(A)B(t) + \mathrm{O}(B(t)^2).
$$
Notice that for $B = B_1$, then $d\exp(A)B(t) + \mathrm{O}(B(t)^2) = td\exp(A)C_1 + \mathrm{O}(t^2)$.

And for all $H$,
$$
d\exp(A)H = \int_0^1 \exp((1 - s)A)H\exp(sA) \, ds,
$$
which equals $\exp(A)H$ if $A$ and $H$ commute. I hope it helps you.

Comment: I guess $B_2(t) = \frac{d}{dt} $ just means $B_2$ is the derivative operator and $\exp(B_2(t))(f) = \sum_{k=0} \frac{1}{k!}\frac{d^kf}{dt^k}(t)$.

Comment: I thought $A$ and $B$ where matrices, please be more clear and explain what belongs to which space. Derivation operators are almost never continuous (because they have arbitrarily large eigenvalues if your space contains the $t \mapsto \exp(\lambda t)$), thus their exponential may not be defined.

Comment: Yes, $A$ and $B$ are $n\times n$ matrices. See the start of section 2 - equations 11, 12, 13, in particular - of this paper (https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/pjab1977/69/7/69_7_161/_pdf) to see how the exponential of $B_2(t)$ is defined on $n\times n$ matrices parameterized by the variable $t$.

Comment: @Cactus What is the $d$ in your answer?

Comment: Ok, so it is the exponential of the matrix as a time dependant operator and not the classical exponential of a matrix. In my answer, $df(x)h$ is the differential of $f$ at a point $x$ evaluated at $h$. Here, $f = \exp$.